# None of the div is using max width of 100% when inspect on mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: Unexpected out]I am working on one project and I have created three pages but when I tried to map them for mobile device, I socked that none of the div class like .container-fuild, row or col-12 is using 100% width. Actually, its using 100% width but for @320 its only utilizing 70-80% of screen.

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
        <div class="header-banner">
            <div class="row pt-2 pb-3 mx-auto no-gutters">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 mx-auto">
                    <div class="header-img-container">
                        <img class="" src="img/grocery.png"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 mx-auto">
                    <div class="header-banner-container pt-5">
                    </div>
                 </div>
           </div>
        </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

This is the part of code that i have shared. I am using bootstrap 4 and tried to map the code for

```
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 320px) 
 and (max-device-width: 480px)
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
```

I am sure that the media has no link with my issue but its my responsibility to update you..

Leads would be appreciate.

Output is shown in the shared image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this issue is clearly caused by the image(s) not on 100% width.

Add a CSS class `img-fluid` to your images and the container will be on 100% as well.

[documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)

*Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with `.img-fluid.` max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.*

Comment: Many Thanks Tim,
I think that I am getting old now a days.. Need to spent more time on YOGA